# VBA Excel Nested For Loop Issue

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create a VBA code to loop through all excel sheet to convert all cells with 2 decimal places number to 8 decimal places, below is the code, only the active sheet has successfully converted, but the rest of the sheet remain same (no conversion happen), can anyone please help.

```
Sub ChangeDecimal()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In Range("A1:AA200")
        If Len(c) - InStr(c, ".") > 2 Then
        c.NumberFormat = "0.00000000"
        End If
    Next c
    
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you expect an error in the respective range of sheets to be processed? If so, you should check them previously. But your code main problem is the fact that you only process the active sheet. You should use `For Each c In ws.Range("A1:AA200")` to process the range in each iterated sheet...

Comment: You need to write `for Each c In ws.Range("A1:AA200")`, else VBA has no clue which sheet you are referring to and always works on the Active Sheet.

Comment: Oh, thank you all, yes it was my mistake, i have missed out the "ws.Range".
Thanks you all for the help.